# Send email with delphi indy from windows service application

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy10

I'm trying to send email with TIdSMTP, Indy10, using the Office365.com server
from a Windows service application.
I use:

- Server name: smtp.office365.com
- Port: 587
- Encryption method: STARTTLS

I use 1.0.2 version of libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll.
They are located in the same directory with the application.

If the windows service application runs under the "Local System Account" credentials, I receive the "Invalid domain name [xxxx.xxxx.OUTLOOK.COM]" error message.
If the application runs as an application or as a Windows service, but with a user's credentials the email is transmitted.

What could it be?

Thanks,
Tiberiu Stoicescu

Comment: At what stage does the error message happen exactly? When connecting to the server? When logging in? When sending an email? Please provide a [mcve] showing how you are using `TIdSMTP` and indicate which line of code is failing. SMTP is not tied to any user account, so any user account can use it. It is just plain TCP networking. So something else is going on behind the scenes. For instance, when the `TIdSMTP.HeloName` property is blank, `TIdSMTP` uses the local machine's hostname when sending the initial `EHLO`/`HELO` command to the server. Maybe Office doesn't like your hostname?

Comment: Thanks for tips. I wil try this.

Comment: I found that when application run as windows service TIdSMTP.HeloName is set with "PRO1.NT AUTHORITY" and space is not accepted.
If I remove spaces all work well.
Thanks again

Comment: Indy does not assign anything to the `HeloName`, that is your responsibility to assign as needed.  If you leave it blank, Indy uses the local machine's host/computer name instead. You might consider using `GetComputerNameEx()` to get the local machine's full qualified DNS name, which is what SMTP is expecting anyway.